# Makeing rig Left/Right (*.L/*.R or *_L/*_R_) compatible

Tags: animation

I'have got a visually symmentrical rig, but the bones have horrible names like
Hand_001, Hand_002 etc.

To make X-axis mirror and related stuff working I need to make the rig conform to
Blender nameing conventions.

I tried to rename Hand.001 and Hand.002 to Hand_L and Hand_R, saved the file, restart
Blender and tried moving the left hand while "x-axis mirror" was active...but it
does not work.

What else need to be changed or handled differently to get things like x-axis mirror while
posing the rig work again?

Comment: The first comment referes to creating a rig. My rig is already finished from external and has wrong bone names.

Comment: AutoRename does the same thing as manual renaming bones as described in my post. I tried AutoRename and it does not work as expected: It renames the bones and X-axis does not work still

Comment: I have had to deal with this kind of thing in models imported from another source, but thankfully it’s fairly easy using the python API. Do you have any Python proficiency?

Comment: I deleted my comments + answer ... and I would suggest - edit your question, since your issue seems to be related to drivers not naming. Change title to something more descriptive. And probably would be helpful to attach your simplified blend to let us see what are you dealing with (use https://blend-exchange.com given code copy-paste into your question). Thank you

Comment: Hang on, I just remember that sometimes x-axis mirror will not automatically copy the rotation for some reason with me. I don’t know why. It does always copy the location though if I’m moving the bone around with a tool.

Comment: Before I re-edit what I asked for: The rig/character in question is completly rigged, has shape keys and drivers and what else might be in there. AND: Its bones are named NOT in conformance to blender standards. X-axis fails due to the last issue in first place. The AutoRename feature is renaming bones only leaving the references to those bone as dead ends behind. Step 1: The bones AND the all references (wherever they are...shape key drivers may only ONE instance) need to be renamed. The drivers themselves are working with correct references. So this problem is related to sane renaming only.